# Need a TRUE and FALSE column in Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a multi-value filter for a Spark SQL DataFrame.

I have:

```
val df: DataFrame      // my data
val field: String      // The field of interest
val values: Array[Any] // The allowed possible values
```

and I'm trying to come up with the filter specification.

At the moment, I have:

```
val filter = values.map(value => df(field) === value)).reduce(_ || _)
```

But this isn't robust in the case where I get passed an empty list of values.  To cover that case, I would like:

```
val filter = values.map(value => df(field) === value)).fold(falseColumn)(_ || _)
```

but I don't know how to specify falseColumn.

Anyone know how to do so?

And is there a better way of writing this filter? (If so, I still need the answer for how to get a falseColumn - I need a trueColumn for a separate piece).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A column that is always true:

```
val trueColumn = lit(true)
```

A column that is always false:

```
val falseColumn = lit(false)
```

Using `lit(...)` means these will always be valid columns, regardless of what columns the DataFrame contains.